# What is the performance impact of exceeding the 8060 bytes per row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

If I create a SQL Server table that has more than  8060 bytes per page, will the querying be considerably hurt for columns that exceed this limit?

I also don't understand quite right if a row occupies the whole 8060 bytes even if it's empty.. in the case it's true, will the query performance be impacted just for the particular rows that exceed the limit or for all rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first Question:

Yes, it could affect performance. Having a combination of varchar, nvarchar, sql_variant and varbinary in one table, with total size greater than 8,060 bytes results in reallocation data to another page. 
While this affects update, I'm not sure if it's too important for reading a data. Internally, SQL Server puts a pointer to the reallocated portion of data within new page so I guess it's quite fast operation.

It's up to you (DBA/developer) to analyze and predict the percentage of such rows in table. If it occurs too often, consider moving large columns into separate table(s).
Use sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats to find out what's going on with your data.

Second Question:

I guess you asked for situation when some columns (especially varchar) are empty. You can "help" SQL Server to save space using [sparse columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx)
Also, I'd recommend [this](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/04/five-things-about-fillfactor/) article.

Comment: We did some tests and you are totally right. Thank you.